# Click event results an error `TypeError: this.$varName.on is not a function` which isn't a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, modular-design

I have this exact code:

```
<span class="btn" id="setScheduleBtn">Set Schedule</span>
    <div id="reportSchedule" name="reportSchedule" style="display: none;">text</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
/******************/
/** Set Schedule **/ 
/******************/
(function() {

    var schedule = {

        report: [], 
        template: $('#report_schedule').html(),

        // Init functions
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        }, 
        // Cache elements from DOM
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$setScheduleBtn = $('#setScheduleBtn'); 
            this.$reportSchedule = $('#reportSchedule');
        }, 
        // Set events
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$setScheduleBtn.on('click', this.showReportScheduler.bind(this));
        }, 
        // Display on click
        showReportScheduler: function() {
            this.$reportSchedule.toggle();
        }

    };
    schedule.init();

})();
</script>
```

Running this code on my local machine project - I get this error result in the console: 
`TypeError: this.$setScheduleBtn.on is not a function`
without toggling. 
jQuery is loaded in the  tag. the html code comes before the script. jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2

This is a JSfiddle with the exact code which runs properly: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t6hprf4x/

What might be the problem?

Comment: try to log "this" in cacheDom and "this" in binEvents ;-) you have differents contexts

Comment: @MarouenMhiri it is the same context, the problem is the jQuery version, that version doesn't have the `on` function.

Comment: so you mean if you use bind instead of on this will work? don't think so

Comment: @MarouenMhiri No, I mean that jQuery v1.3.2 doesn't have an `on` function. He will have to use `this.$setScheduleBtn.click(this.showReportScheduler.bind(this));` to add a click listener to the element.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri If you take a look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ you will see that this function was added in version `1.7`

Comment: @Titus ah cool! didn't knew that! thx! you have to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on) The `on` function was added in version `1.7` that means that the version you're using doesn't have this function.

You will have to use a newer version of the library or add the click listener using the `click` function.

```
this.$setScheduleBtn.click(this.showReportScheduler.bind(this));
```